# How to configure custom domains in SAAS solution (Windows Azure)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dns, a-records

We are building SAAS solution on Windows Azure. Every customer should have possibility to map his custom domain (example.com) to our service.

According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981933.aspx) there are two options for mapping custom domain to Azure hosted service:

1. CNAME record (requires a subdomain, like www). Not a case. Option without subdomain is must have.
2. Map an A record to VIP (virtual IP). This is better. It is mentioned that: "The VIP of the deployment is guaranteed not to change unless the deployment for the hosted service is deleted". But a few days ago our IP was suddenly changed without deleting. Currently it is a trial account (90 days) and only one instance is used. Probably that could be a reason.

At first we planned to map custom domains (example.com, etc) to VIP using A record, but it seems it is not stable. At least in trial it is not.

Has anyone built something similar? How to accomplish stable mapping for custom domains?

Comment: Many domain registrars support redirection (or "forwarding"). E.g., smarx.com gets you to my blog (hosted on Windows Azure), but only after GoDaddy redirects smarx.com to blog.smarx.com. You could do the same, so example.com redirects to www.example.com, which is a CNAME to Windows Azure. Visit "microsoft.com" or "amazon.com" to see a similar thing happen.

Comment: I've read that GoDaddy allows to configure redirects. As I understood they use dedicated servers on their ends for that. Our local (Ukrainian) provider doesn't allow to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be with option 1 above.  Your service can go down for any number of reasons and all of which don't guarantee that the VIP will stay the same.  So the safest way would be to use a CNAME.

Comment: option 1 is not so good for us. Lot of users don't use www at the beginning, so this is some kind of restrictions that we are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with CNAME because this is what has been used prominently by Windows Azure users worldwide, however as Windows Azure Guarantee that VIP will not change during the life of service so as long as you don't delete the service, so you sure can use it. I have seen users start using it as also.

-> About your claim that VIP changed even when you did not delete your service, I would say that must not happen even with a trial account.

- How did you deploy your application? If you deploy your application
  in a way that the previous deployment is deleted and a new deployment
  is created, this may cause change in VIP. For example the deployment
  from VS, delete the existed deployment and then create a new
  deployment which will result the same behavior. It is always good to
  update an existing deployment and be sure the process you are using
  is doing an upgrade (no delete + new deployment).

If above was not your case, and you are sure your VIP changed without deleting the existing deployment, this should be notified to Windows Azure support team because Windows Azure claim that VIP will not change during the life of service as long as it is not deleted.

Comment: Yes, I've checked a lot of articles about VIP. They say it is guaranteed not to change unless the deployment for the hosted service is deleted. We use publish from VS, so no deleting, just upgrading. Anyway thanks, I'll probably contact MS for advice. P.S. I don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as useful.

Comment: If you deploy from VS, it actually delete the deployment and then create a new deployment that's why your VIP got changed. AFAIK VS does not support upgrade service option. You need to use either Powershell or upgrade directly at portal to keep your service intact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am really surprised with such behavior of VS. I'll check documentation for more info.